# CSS: Overflow:hidden removing border-bottom?

Tags: html, css, overflow, border

I am making a HTML page, and have attempted to set a `<a>` tag a `border-bottom`.

It would **not** show, whatever I did. So I made a reduced test case that can be seen here:

http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/ILKdx

Happens in FF beta, and Chrome 22.

If I remove the `overflow:hidden;` or change it to `overflow:visible`, it works. The problem is that I **need** to have that set.

So how can I have a border-bottom? (or is it me :) )

(I cannot use text-underline, want it dotted)

Thanks

Harley

Comment: for test, specify `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @Shmiddty Can you make your comment a answer? I want to tick it! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`display:inline-block;` on the link seems to do the trick.

Comment: Only in modern browsers though.

Comment: @PerSalbark Which wont I work in? I need IE8 + compatibility.

Answer (score 9):

Add `1px` of padding on the top and bottom of the grid:

```
.grid{overflow:hidden; padding: 1px 0px;}
```

OR

Make the grid element inline:

```
.grid{overflow:hidden; display: inline;}
```

There's probably a hundred different ways of solving this really.

Comment: @harley Although each may have its own negative side effects,  that we've already seen three ways of solving it and there's probably many more (I can think of a few more off the top of my head). You just need to find which solution works the best for you.

Comment: Surely though, as styles are meant to cascade, if you set overflow:visible to a, then it should just...  work? (Thanks a Lot anyway.)

Comment: @harley, I'm not sure I understand your last comment, you said overflow:hidden was a requirement.

Comment: Sorry, I meant (in the comment) the **a** tag. IE Set overflow to visible on the **a** tag. (typing too fast..)

Comment: This is such a weird 'bug', padding:1px 0px; fixes it. I tried display:inline but im using a fluid grid so it makes the items resize real quick when navigating through steps in a tabbed interface.

Answer (score 3):

try increasing the line-height. eg. add `line-height:200%;` to the #test css

Comment: Sorry, It messes up the layout.

Answer (score 0):

In my case any solutions didn't work for me.

I solved the problem by add blank div after last trouble-making div.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add this to my element:
display: table;
width: 95%;